# jQuery Selector for ahref within .html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, href, selector

I am trying to use jQuery to select all the  elements within the .html() functions and run a message on click. However this is not working, does anyone here know why?

```
    function load_tweets(user) {
      var $body = $('body');
      while(index >= 0){
        var $tweet = $('<div class="tweet"></div>');
        $tweet.html("<span class='tweetText'>"+tweet.created_at + ' <a href="#" class="'+tweet.user+'">@' + tweet.user + '</a>: ' + tweet.message+"</span>");
        $tweet.appendTo($body);

        index -= 1;
      }
    }
    $("a[href='#']").click(function() {
        alert($(this).attr("class"));
    });
```

Comment: Any js errors in console? Did you use a DOM ready event? Reference to `$body`? `index` is a global? Empty selector perhaps => html?

Comment: No errors in console. Yes I used a DOM ready event. And forgot to include the body line, it's defined right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to find the elements *BEFORE* you insert them. You have to put your `$("a[href='#']")` code *AFTER* you insert your elements.

Or just use this instead. `$("body").on("click", "a[href='#']", function() {`